# jQuery on scroll header effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, effects

***Hi guys***

I would like to make a **jquery on scroll header effect**. I've just added some changes in to the code
but it's not working they way I want.
I want to make the effect  - when I scroll down a bit pixel for the header to change the height to small. Or show the hidden header with other styles

So when scrolling the normal header to slide up and then show the hidden header like slide down...
I've spent much time on this but it's only working with **fadeIn** and **fadeOut**

```
 jQuery code

 $(function() {
    $('.header-small').hide();
    var header = $(".header-small");
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 200) {
            $('.header-small').show();


            header.removeClass('header').addClass("header-small");
            $('.header-small').addClass('animated fadeInUp'), {duration:500};


        } else {
            $('header').show();
            $('.header-small').hide();
            header.removeClass("header-small").addClass('header');
            $('header').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
        }
    });
});
```

**Working demo** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qm4Zp/2/embedded/result/%22)

Please could somebody help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try using callbacks,

```
$(function() {
        $('.header-small').hide();
        var bar = $('header');
        var top = bar.css('top');
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                bar.stop().animate({'top' : '0px'}, 200);
                $('.header-small').slideDown('slow',function(){

                    $('header').slideUp('slow');});
            } else {
                bar.stop().animate({'top' : '20px'}, 200);
                    $('header').slideDown('slow');
                    $('.header-small').slideUp('slow');
            }
        });
    });
```

And also some styling for cleaner effect

```
header
{
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
}
```

[Jsfiddle updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/qm4Zp/8/)

Answer (score -1):

Why not just addClass and do the rest in CSS?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('header').addClass('header-small');
  }
  else {
    $('header').removeClass('header-small');
  }
});
```

Comment: Because he's trying to animate the size of the header as it shrinks and grows.

Comment: @DevIshOne Yes you can do that with CSS3. Much more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: For example CSS transform if the dimensions change will create a smooth transition: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Then you should have posted the corresponding CSS with your suggestion. Please, show us the code. Thanks.

Comment: I was merely suggesting another solution. I don't have time to write all the CSS3 animation code from scratch for people. Nonetheless, my solution will work with the correct CSS.

Comment: I would suggest you read the section on submitting answers. An answer like this would fit better in the comments section since it is not a complete answer and doesn't really help the OP make any progress towards a solid solution. Thanks

Comment: thanks for everybody i finded animate css and added in to jquery now it looks like very well only i am not sure if the code i ok

Answer (score -1):

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/qm4Zp/11/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.header-small').hide();
    var bar = $('header');
    var top = bar.css('top');
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            bar.stop().animate({
                'top': '0px'
            }, 200);
            $('header').slideUp('fast', function () {
                $('.header-small').slideDown('slow');
            });
        } else {
            bar.stop().animate({
                'top': '20px'
            }, 200);
            $('.header-small').slideUp('fast', function () {
                $('header').slideDown('fast');
            });
        }
    });
});
```